# Was bedeutet "das was"?

Tags: dialect

Wenn die Kassiererin mich fragen möchte, ob ich noch etwas mehr einkaufen möchte, fragt sie schnell

> Das was?

Was bedeutet das? Ist das mit *Das war's?* gleichbedeutend?

Comment: Ich bin mir sicher, sie sagte "das war's" und hat das r nur sehr undeutlich ausgesprochen

Comment: Das was hast du überhört...? Das 'r'? Und was das bedeutet, ist klar. Closed. Das war's. (<-- bitte nicht so ernst nehmen, es ist spät)

Comment: Du hast deine Frage mit dem Tag `dialects` versehen. Es wäre dann vielleicht interessant, in welcher Gegend du das gehört hast.

Comment: @Takkat: user16... hat sich verhört - fang doch jetzt nicht mit Dialekten an!

Comment: Questions, based on wrong assumptions will hardly find interest in future. They fit the now removed topic `too narrow/private`.

Comment: In Köln! @Takkat

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mit ziemlicher Sicherheit hat die Kassiererin gefragt:

> Das war's?

Dass du das *r* nicht wahrgenommen hast, liegt daran, dass viele Deutsch-Sprecherinnen und -Sprecher ein *r* im Silbenauslaut als Zentralvokal [ɐ] realisieren. [Dieser Vokal wird auch *a-Schwa*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_offener_Zentralvokal)  genannt, weil er so wie ein reduziertes *a* klingt. Da der vorhergehende Vokal schon ein *a* war, kann also das *r* in *das war's* akustisch untergehen.
Trotzdem sollte meines Erachtens ein deutlicher Unterschied zwischen *was* und *war's* wahrnehmbar sein: [Ersteres](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/was#Pronomen) enthält einen kurzen Vokal [a], [letzteres](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/war#war_.28Deutsch.29) ein langes [aːɐ̯].

Comment: I also understood "das was?" but you did not answer the question. Since I am not German, I think "das war's?" is the abbreviation for "das war es?" or "das war alles?" ("that's all?" in English) but I am not sure.

Comment: "das war's" = "das war es"; compare "'s gibt's nicht" = "das gibt es nicht", "jetzt geht's los" = "jetzt geht es los" etc.