# What are the standard responses to the question "Das war's?"

Tags: phrase

Often in shops/bakeries/etc within NRW, Germany, a common way of asking *Is that everything?* is to ask *Das war's?* as a question. (*Das war's* comes across as if it is pronounced as *Das was*, [though this question suggests that *das war's* is what is in fact said.](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18475/was-bedeutet-das-was))

In my experience as a German learner, I often reply with *Das ist alles.* but I've never seen another German speaker answer in this way.  I often observe that when no additional items are required, the question *Das war's?* is often typically answered with *Das war's.*.

Am I correct in my observation? What is the standard answer when there are more items to be added to the purchase?

Comment: I think in form of a question it's more usual to say _War's das?_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Both user1626485 in https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18475/was-bedeutet-das-was and I observe *Das war's?* not *War's das?* as the typical phrasing.

Comment: Well, that depends on context: If it's you're asked at the supermarket's check-out, or you ask yourself the project lead after he had told you, you're no longer a team member, all makes a difference.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I thought "Das war's." at a supermarket check-out was called "Warentrenner".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper :-D At least not as a question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm a native German speaker and I often answer

> Das wär' alles

which is short for *das wäre alles* (that would be everything [I want to buy]). This also works for similar questions ("Darf's noch etwas sein?")

But there are no laws on how to answer this question, so you may choose any of the following or come up with a different one of your own

> Ja, danke
> (Ja,) das war's
> Ja, das ist/war/wär'/wäre alles.

if you are not done, you can just continue with your purchases

> Seller: Das war's?
> Purchaser: Nein, ich hätte gerne noch XYZ

Comment: Note that you usually omit the apostrophe: "wär"

Comment: Incidentally, I think the question tends to be “das wär's” too or “wär das alles”, not “das war's”.

Answer (score 3):

I do not often hear the question "Das war's?", but usually "Noch einen Wunsch?" or "Haben Sie noch einen Wunsch?". Perhaps there are regional differences in language use. In my opinion "Das war's?" is less polite, but maybe I am out-dated in that respect.

Anyway, you can answer

1. Ja, danke.
2. Ja.
3. Ja, danke, das war's.
4. Danke, das war's.
5. Ja, das war's.
6. Das war's.

The polite versions are those with "danke", but as I said, I do not think the question itself is a good example for polite communication. Therefore also the other variants should be okay.

If you decide for 6. you must of course take care of proper intonation (as in English):

Das war's ↗︎ ? (rising intonation)

Das war's ↘︎ . (falling intonation)

Comment: _"I do not often hear the question "Das war's?""_ I'd even consider this a little bit unkind or unfriendly. Not the appropriate behavior to talk with customers.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Ja - hat eine unangenehme Ähnlichkeit mit "War's das jetzt endlich?"

Comment: Occansionally I hear *Das war's?* being made more in the more polite form of *Das war's für Sie?*

Answer (score 2):

If someone asks you

> Das war's?

The most common answer is

> Ja, danke.

I think its comparable to English... if someone asks you if you want anything else and you don't, you also thank them for asking and serving you.

Comment: As per my observations (stated in the question), the most common answer to *Das war's?* is *Das war's.* which is listed as a possible answer in infintezero's answer. I'm not sure that I agree with either the logic or the conclusion of this answer.

Comment: for example: you place you order with the waitress, after youre done he/she asks "das wars?" and you really answer "das wars"? I highly recommend to say "Ja, danke" 100% of the time.

Answer (score 2):

While infinitezero's answer sums it up quite nicely I want to expand on the subtleties as the comments are full of variations and nuances regarding "wär(s)" vs. "war(s)" and rudeness. That aspect is highly influenced by the region and dialect. In general "wär" is a bit nicer and less direct than "war" just like the English "want" vs "would like". `Is that all you want`in comparison to `Is that all you would like` is the direct english equivalent. "Das war's" can sound quite easily like a statement and has to be pronounced quite precisely to come across as a normal question without further implications. "Das wär's" is more thoughtful and probably safer.

Now in regard to the region: the south of German is generally more polite and also more inclined towards "ä/ö"-sounds. So while a harshly spoken "Das war's?" probably would not get you a strange look in Berlin, it probably would in a village in the south.

I would personally refrain from answering "Das war's?" with "Das war's!" because it sounds a little weird like I am imitating the asker. My usual replies are "Ja", "Ja, das war's" or really just a nod. Other replies I use depending on the context are "Für heute, ja", "Erstmal, ja" and "Ich denke schon" (I think so).

Comment: YMMV: to me the question "Das war's?" is sloppy enough to not invest much sympathy into my answer either (I don't feel insulted either). How about being schlagfertig and answering with "erstmal ja" or "sagten Sie grad Star Wars?"